# How can I grab the src within this iframe using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox, iframe, beautifulsoup

Here's the iframe:

```html
<iframe allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen="yes" frameborder="no" scrolling="no" src="https://www.example.com" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>
```

My attempt:

```py
print(soup.find("iframe")["src"])
```

Additional Info for this case:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("https://9anime.to/watch/puella-magi-madoka-magica.q1n/yqq3r9x")
time.sleep(5)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
print(soup.find("iframe"))

driver.quit()
```

The 'Additional Info' code will work copy/paste if you want to find the exact html. (Could also add `print(soup.prettify())` at the very end for the whole html script.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**  `(soup.find("iframe")["src"]`

In my case:  `print((soup.find("iframe"))["src"])`